# Paypal PDT does not return transaction for subscription with free trial

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-pdt

I'm working with Paypal PDT, everything is working very good, Paypal will return transaction details for any payment with charged amount; but does not return for subscription with free trial period

I need to secure the payment by referrer identify, but in Paypal's success page, seems it also does not pass referrer so my PHP code can not detect it.

I found referrer will be returned if you set "rm" (returned method) is POST (2). **But this referrer only returned when user clicks return link manually, if Paypal auto redirects to return page, it does not return referrer**

Please help me with right solutions, please don't suggest IPN.

Many thanks

Comment: how you solved this?

Comment: pls try to use Paypal IPN, it's better, it gives you auto cancel, very good & strong to handle payment automatic totally

Comment: I have a cancell subscription button, how to manage using ipn, is their any documentation available in paypal?

Comment: go to their site for URL, they changed many times, so I cant remember

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

variable 'period1'  and 'period2' are for PDT Trial subscription